# curl 127.0.0.1 and localhost behave differently (hosts file is good)

Tags: proxy, localhost

I ran into weird issue on dev server. CentOS 6.5.
If I curl from bash script to "127.0.0.1" I get 403 response. It tries to go through corporate proxy. Details below.

If I curl to "localhost" - it's good.

Why this can be happening and how to prevent it?

I want to use 127.0.0.1 as a safer option (on some of production servers localhost may not be set).

**curl to 127.0.0.1 log:**

```
 About to connect() to proxy 172.1.0.65 port 3128 (#0)
*   Trying 172.11.0.63... connected
* Connected to 172.11.0.63 (172.11.0.63) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to 10.235.1.195:443
 > CONNECT 10.235.1.195:443 HTTP/1.1
 > Host: 10.235.1.195:443
 > User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7
 > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
 >
 < HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

**curl to localhost log:**

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 443 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   bla-bla-bla
> POST /link/to/page HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 43
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
} [data not shown]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 03 Aug 2018 14:50:40 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
```

**cat /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: Have you tried unsetting the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable?

Comment: please also post an equivalent *curl to localhost log*

Comment: @EugenRieck yes, but that's not the question :D

Comment: @gollum nothing interesting there - route goes straight to 127.0.0.1 and results in 200

Comment: So you definitely don't see a proxy connection if you curl to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Have you checked your `NO_PROXY` environment variable?

Comment: *on some of production servers localhost may not be set* this will break a lot of stuff and there is no reason not to define `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`. It is shipped like that in all standard Linux distributions...

Comment: You do not show what happens when you do `curl localhost`.  Depending on `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` this may get "expanded" to a completely different name...

Comment: The `HTTP_PROXY` might very well be the question! It will make curl use a proxy if the requested address is not in a (very short) list. It might easily be, that localhost is on that list and 127.0.0.1 is not.

Comment: What does `ping localhost` and `ping 127.0.0.1` say?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I updated the post and added localhost log.

Comment: @confetti Not sure what ping gives you but here is traceroute to localhost (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.035 ms  0.015 ms  0.011 ms

Comment: @PatrickMevzek /etc/hosts contents is in post, /etc/resolv.conf contains only two namserver records... btw thank you for your time

Comment: You clearly have some sort of proxy set up. This is why I asked for a ping, but the curl confirmed it too.

Comment: @confetti Yes. Proxy is definitely set up - it's not a surprise - we set it ourselves. The question is - why proxy is used when addressing loopback (!) by 127.0.0.1 and not used when addressing it by host (!!)? Maybe it's wrong forum? Is there a better place to lookup answers for network and server administration?

Comment: @confetti I just noticed that localhost is getting connected directly to ::1 via port 443. I assume this bypasses proxy and have a vague idea why.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I think I'm dumb. I just noticed that localhost is resolved as ::1. I still don't understand why this bypasses proxy.

Comment: As I said - the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable is indeed important: Since it contains an IPv4 address it is used for IPv4 targets (such as 127.0.0.1) but not for IPv6 targets (such as localhost in your setup).

Comment: @EugenRieck You are genius. That is so obvious when you understand this. Thank you!