# Why does `curl <this machine's IP>` behave differently than `curl localhost`?

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, port-forwarding, ip-address

(Redirected from [networkengineering.stackexchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66889/why-does-curl-this-machines-ip-behave-differently-than-curl-localhost?noredirect=1#comment118550_66889))

I have two Raspberry Pis on my network - let's call them Pi and Rho.

I'm trying to set up port forwarding via ssh tunnel between them, such that an application can connect to a port on Rho and get results from a server listening on a port on Pi (my eventual goal is actually to set up port forwarding such that a host on a different network could get access to a Samba share on Pi via an ssh connection to Rho, without my having to entirely open a firewall port to Pi).

Pi's IP in my LAN is `192.168.42.69`, and Rho's is `192.168.42.112` - these are the IPs that I ssh to from my local network to connect to them.

In order to test this, I have started a minimal Python server (with `SimpleHTTPServer`) on Pi's port 8000, and run `sudo ssh -L 140:localhost:8000 root@192.168.42.69 -N` on Rho. When I `curl localhost:140` or `curl 127.0.0.1:140` on Rho, I get the response I expect. However, when I `curl 192.168.42.112:140` on Rho, I get a connection refused; verbose output below:

```
$ curl -vvv 192.168.42.112:140
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x2cd880)
*   Trying 192.168.42.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x2cd880)
* connect to 192.168.42.112 port 140 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.42.112 port 140: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.42.112 port 140: Connection refused
```

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Having [checked this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1344855/curl-127-0-0-1-and-localhost-behave-differently-hosts-file-is-good), I confirmed that the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` is not set on Rho, nor is `NO_PROXY`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your ssh command, you are not specifying a `bind_address` for your `-L` option.

According to [`man ssh`:](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the `GatewayPorts` setting. However, an explicit `bind_address` may be used to bind the connection to a specific address. The `bind_address` of `localhost` indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or `*` indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.

To allow connections on all interfaces and not just `localhost` (which is an alias for `127.0.0.1`, the address of the [loopback interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)), specify a `bind_address` of `0.0.0.0` in your `-L` option, e.g.

```
sudo ssh -L 0.0.0.0:140:localhost:8000 root@192.168.42.69 -N
```

If you would prefer it listen on a particular IP, you can specify it instead of `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: TIL, thanks! An alternative I found was to use `sudo ssh -o GatewayPorts=yes -L 140:localhost:8000 ...`

Answer (score 5):

This is what [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#L) states:

> ```
> -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
> -L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
> -L local_socket:host:hostport
> -L local_socket:remote_socket
> ```
>
> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side. […]
>
> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the `GatewayPorts` setting. However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the connection to a specific address. The bind_address of `localhost` indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or `*` indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.

`GatewayPorts` mentioned is the one from `ssh_config` (not the one from `sshd_config`, this one is for `-R`). From [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#GatewayPorts):

> ```
> GatewayPorts
> ```
>
> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local forwarded ports. By default, `ssh(1)` binds local port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. `GatewayPorts` can be used to specify that `ssh` should bind local port forwardings to the wildcard address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports. The argument must be `yes` or `no` (the default).

Your command

> ```
> ssh -L 140:localhost:8000 root@192.168.42.69 -N
> ```

does not specify `bind_address`, it qualifies to "by default". It looks like `GatewayPorts` for `ssh` is `no`.

Note "an empty address" looks differently: `-L :140:localhost:8000`. The extra colon matters. This variant *does* specify `bind_address` as an empty string, while `-L 140:localhost:8000` you used does not specify `bind_address` at all.

To bind to all interfaces use an empty address (`-L :140:localhost:8000`) or `*` (in a shell you should quote it, e.g. `-L '*':140:localhost:8000`).